# Send HTML Structured Email with Attachment from project folder using mail function in PHP

Tags: php, html, email, html-email, email-attachments

anyone who can help me to add the code on how to send an HTML Structured Email with Attachment from Project folder using mail function in PHP.

Please review below code I constructed.

```
$mail_to = 'receiver@gmail.com';
$mail_subject = 'Sample Document Name';
$mail_headers = [
   'MIME-Version'  => '1.0', 
   'Content-Type'  => 'text/html;charset=UTF-8', 
   'From'          => 'PROJECT', 
   'Reply-To'      => 'reply@gmail.com'
];

$mail_receiver_name = 'Sample Receiver Name';
$mail_document_type_name = 'Sample Document Type';
$mail_document_subject = 'Sample Subject';
$mail_document_number = 'Sample Document Number';
$mail_document_remarks = 'Sample Remarks';

ob_start();
require_once('mail_template.php');
$mail_message = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$send = mail($mail_to, $mail_subject, $mail_message, $mail_headers);

$output = $send ? 'success' : 'success but email was not sent';

echo $output;
```

Comment: Is this of some help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail

Comment: @KenLee I usually like your suggestions.  Do I really need `PHPMailer` these days to send an email?  What's wrong with the built-in `mail()`

Comment: Hi @Misunderstood, actually the PHP mail() works, but PHPMailer is another alternative. (I just answered the OP's question, using mail() only)

Answer (score 0):

1. Please add your email address in the `From` part of the headers , For example :

```
$mail_headers[] =  'From: Project <realaddress@gmail.com>';
```

2. Please implode your headers array by using `implode("\r\n", $mail_headers)` when you use mail()

So use:

```
mail($mail_to, $mail_subject, $mail_message, implode("\r\n", $mail_headers));
```

So please use the following (tested - it works)

PHP

```
<?php
$mail_to = 'realreceiver@gmail.com';

$mail_subject = 'Sample Document Name';

$mail_headers[] =  'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$mail_headers[] =  'Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8'; 
$mail_headers[] =  'From: Project <realaddress@gmail.com>'; 
$mail_headers[] =  'Reply-To :realaddress@gmail.com'; 



$mail_receiver_name = 'Sample Receiver Name';
$mail_document_type_name = 'Sample Document Type';
$mail_document_subject = 'Sample Subject';
$mail_document_number = 'Sample Document Number';
$mail_document_remarks = 'Sample Remarks';

ob_start();
require_once('mail_template.php');
$mail_message = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();



$send = mail($mail_to, $mail_subject, $mail_message, implode("\r\n", $mail_headers));

$output = $send ? 'success' : 'success but email was not sent';

echo $output;

?>
```

mail_template.php (can be something like the following:)

```
Hello Ken 

<br>
<?php echo $mail_receiver_name; ?>
<br>
<?php echo $mail_document_type_name; ?>
<br>
<?php echo $mail_document_subject; ?>
<br>
<?php echo $mail_document_number; ?>
<br>
<?php echo $mail_document_remarks; ?>
```

** Please use your own email addresses to replace the above "realaddress@gmail.com" and "realreceiver@gmail.com" email accounts.